# Eliminar una row de un Datagrid mientras itera en un foreach?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo un datagridview que contiene distintos registros y un timer respectivo en cada row, necesito que al momento de que el timer llegue a 0 se elimine el row y se traspase a otro datagrid, pero me tira error producto a que no se puede eliminar una fila mientras el foreach esté corriendo, pero como trabajo con timer es inevitable no tener corriendo el foreach ya que trabaja permanentemente, alguna alternativa para eliminar la fila donde el timer esté en 0 y cambiarlo a otro datagrid?

```
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();


        dtStopwatches.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        dtStopwatches.Columns.Add("Nombre", typeof(string));
        dtStopwatches.Columns.Add("Tiempo Restante", typeof(string));
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dtStopwatches;

        foreach (string buttonName in new string[] { "Pausar/Reanudar", "Reset", "Restart" })
        {
            DataGridViewButtonColumn colTemp = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            colTemp.Name = buttonName + "Col";
            colTemp.HeaderText = buttonName;
            colTemp.Width = 100;
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(colTemp);
        }

        timer1.Tick += (timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Interval = 1000;
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) <----- AQUÍ EL PROBLEMA
    {


        timer1.Stop();


        foreach (DataRow dRow in dtStopwatches.Rows)
        {

            int hours = int.Parse((TimeSpan.Parse(swDct[(int)dRow["ID"]].Elapsed.ToString()) - TimeSpan.Parse(1.ToString())).ToString(@"hh")) - 23; // <----- ASIGNACIÓN DE HORAS (24 - horas deseadas)
            int mins = int.Parse((TimeSpan.Parse(swDct[(int)dRow["ID"]].Elapsed.ToString()) - TimeSpan.Parse(1.ToString())).ToString(@"mm")) - 59; // <----- ASIGNACIÓN DE MINUTOS (60 - minutos deseados)
            int secs = int.Parse(((TimeSpan.Parse(swDct[(int)dRow["ID"]].Elapsed.ToString()) - TimeSpan.Parse(1.ToString())).ToString(@"ss"))) - 55; // <------ ASIGNACIÓN DE SEGUNDOS (60 - segundos deseados)



            if (hours == 0 && mins == 0 && secs == 0)
            {
                swDct[(int)dRow["ID"]].Stop();
                //dtStopwatches.Rows.Remove(dRow); **<--- en este punto debería eliminarse el row**
            }

            string temp = hours.ToString("00") + ":"
            + mins.ToString("00") + ":"
            + secs.ToString("00");

            dRow["Tiempo Restante"] = temp;


        }


        timer1.Start();



    }

    private void BtnAddStopwatch_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dtStopwatches.Rows.Add(nextID, txt_nombre.Text, "00:00:00");
        swDct.Add(nextID, new Stopwatch());
        nextID++;
        Stopwatch swTemp = swDct[(int)dataGridView1.Rows[temp].Cells["ID"].Value];
        swTemp.Start();
        temp++;
    }

    private void DataGridView1_CellClick_1(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex > -1)
        {
            Stopwatch swTemp = swDct[(int)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ID"].Value];
            switch (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText)
            {
                case "Pausar/Reanudar":
                    if (swDct[(int)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["ID"].Value].IsRunning == true)
                    {   swTemp.Stop();}
                    else{
                        swTemp.Start();}
                     break;
                case "Reset":
                    swTemp.Reset();
                    break;
                case "Restart":
                    swTemp.Restart();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Podrias cambiarte en vez de un foreach con un iterator? , iterator te permite eliminar , foreach como tu mismo dices no te lo permite.

Comment: como funciona eso?, nunca lo he ocupado

Answer (score 0):

Buen día

Usando un ciclo for en vez de un foreach deberia funcionarte asi:

```
    for(int i = 0; i == 0; i++)
    {
        DataRow drow = dtStopwatches.Rows[i];

        int hours = int.Parse((TimeSpan.Parse(swDct[(int)dRow["ID"]].Elapsed.ToString()) - TimeSpan.Parse(1.ToString())).ToString(@"hh")) - 23; // <----- ASIGNACIÓN DE HORAS (24 - horas deseadas)
        int mins = int.Parse((TimeSpan.Parse(swDct[(int)dRow["ID"]].Elapsed.ToString()) - TimeSpan.Parse(1.ToString())).ToString(@"mm")) - 59; // <----- ASIGNACIÓN DE MINUTOS (60 - minutos deseados)
        int secs = int.Parse(((TimeSpan.Parse(swDct[(int)dRow["ID"]].Elapsed.ToString()) - TimeSpan.Parse(1.ToString())).ToString(@"ss"))) - 55; // <------ ASIGNACIÓN DE SEGUNDOS (60 - segundos deseados)



        if (hours == 0 && mins == 0 && secs == 0)
        {
            swDct[(int)dRow["ID"]].Stop();
            dtStopwatches.Rows.RemoveAt(i);//aca lo eliminas por ID
        }

        string temp = hours.ToString("00") + ":"
        + mins.ToString("00") + ":"
        + secs.ToString("00");

        dRow["Tiempo Restante"] = temp;


    }
```

Hay lo que faltaría controlar es el tema de cuando mi cantidad de rows sea igual a mi contador, hay tendrías que reiniciar el contador, Espero sirva.

Answer (score 0):

El `foreach` no funciona pues alteras la colección al eliminar un elemento.
La técnica habitual es realizar un `for` en sentido inverso.

```
for(int i = dtStopwatches.Rows.Count-1; i == 0; i--)
{
    DataRow drow = dtStopwatches.Rows[i];

    int hours = int.Parse((TimeSpan.Parse(swDct[(int)dRow["ID"]].Elapsed.ToString()) - TimeSpan.Parse(1.ToString())).ToString(@"hh")) - 23; // <----- ASIGNACIÓN DE HORAS (24 - horas deseadas)
    int mins = int.Parse((TimeSpan.Parse(swDct[(int)dRow["ID"]].Elapsed.ToString()) - TimeSpan.Parse(1.ToString())).ToString(@"mm")) - 59; // <----- ASIGNACIÓN DE MINUTOS (60 - minutos deseados)
    int secs = int.Parse(((TimeSpan.Parse(swDct[(int)dRow["ID"]].Elapsed.ToString()) - TimeSpan.Parse(1.ToString())).ToString(@"ss"))) - 55; // <------ ASIGNACIÓN DE SEGUNDOS (60 - segundos deseados)

    if (hours == 0 && mins == 0 && secs == 0)
    {
        swDct[(int)dRow["ID"]].Stop();
        dtStopwatches.Rows.RemoveAt(i);   //Eliminamos la fila según el ID
    }

    string temp = hours.ToString("00") + ":"
    + mins.ToString("00") + ":"
    + secs.ToString("00");

    dRow["Tiempo Restante"] = temp;
}
```